# Problema usando spread()

Tags: r, tidyverse

Olá, Tudo bem?
Estou com dificuldades em usar a função `spread()`: ele apresenta erro e não desempilha.

```
dados<-structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), class = "Date"), 
    EST = c("EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", 
    "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", 
    "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", 
    "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", 
    "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", 
    "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", 
    "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", "EST01", 
    "EST02", "EST02"), TT = new("Period", .Data = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 
    10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 
    17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 0, 0), 
        minute = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
    variable = c("SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB", 
    "SensorA", "SensorB", "SensorA", "SensorB"), valor = c(0.013, 
    -0.073, 0.018, -0.125, 0.022, -0.169, 0.019, -0.154, 0.019, 
    -0.144, 0.021, -0.154, 0.021, -0.186, 0.021, -0.181, 0.021, 
    -0.203, 0.021, -0.189, 0.023, -0.185, 0.027, -0.211, 0.049, 
    -0.196, 0.08, -0.048, 0.049, 0.17, 0.026, 0.223, 0.036, 0.312, 
    0.045, 0.386, 0.041, 0.431, 0.031, 0.424, 0.022, 0.389, 0.028, 
    0.308, 0.042, 0.156, 0.021, 0.078, 0.013, -0.073)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

quando tento usar:

```
dados%>%spread(variable,valor)
```

ele da erro:

> Erro: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of
> keys. Keys are shared for 48 rows:
>
> - 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47
> - 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48
>
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

eu precisava que ele fizesse o que esta função esta fazendo, ou seja desemplilhar: (sei que a coluna variable ficou duplicada e por isso acrescentou .x e .y)

Eu entendo que ocorre duplicação de informação pois ele esta desempilhando apenas pela coluna variable, neste caso como colcar mais colunas, veja que na função `merge()` para dois `subset()` eu usei mais colunas de referência.

```
merge(subset(dados%>%rename(`SensorA`=valor),variable=="SensorA"),subset(dados%>%rename(`SensorB`=valor),variable=="SensorB"), by=c("V1","EST","TT"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `spread` é notoriamente difícil de usar. Por isso o pacote `tidyr` agora recomenda `pivot_wider`. De `help("spread")`:

> Development on spread() is complete, and for new code we recommend switching to pivot_wider(), which is easier to use, more featureful, and still under active development. df %>% spread(key, value) is equivalent to df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value)
>
> See more details in vignette("pivot").

Tradução Google, editada, com ênfase minha:

> O desenvolvimento de spread() está completo e, **para o novo código, recomendamos mudar para pivot_wider()**, que é mais fácil de usar, com mais recursos e ainda em desenvolvimento ativo. df%>% spread(key, valor) é equivalente a df%>% pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value)
>
> Veja mais detalhes em vignette("pivot").

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dados %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = -c(variable, valor),
    names_from = variable,
    values_from = valor
  )
## A tibble: 25 x 5
#   V1         EST   TT       SensorA SensorB
#   <date>     <chr> <Period>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 1970-01-02 EST01 0S         0.013  -0.073
# 2 1970-01-02 EST01 1H 0M 0S   0.018  -0.125
# 3 1970-01-02 EST01 2H 0M 0S   0.022  -0.169
# 4 1970-01-02 EST01 3H 0M 0S   0.019  -0.154
# 5 1970-01-02 EST01 4H 0M 0S   0.019  -0.144
# 6 1970-01-02 EST01 5H 0M 0S   0.021  -0.154
# 7 1970-01-02 EST01 6H 0M 0S   0.021  -0.186
# 8 1970-01-02 EST01 7H 0M 0S   0.021  -0.181
# 9 1970-01-02 EST01 8H 0M 0S   0.021  -0.203
#10 1970-01-02 EST01 9H 0M 0S   0.021  -0.189
## … with 15 more rows
```